# What happens if two different elementary particles with different charges collide?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, charge, feynman-diagrams

For example, the up type quark and electron, or down type quark and up type quark. What will happen then? What will be absorbed or radiated? In the end, what kind of particles will turn out? Will it annihilate?
These questions have been bothering me a lot for several days now, but there is no answer on the internet. Please answer, and I am even more concerned about what the Feynman diagrams look like in these cases.

Comment: Colliding particles is not really about colliding them, but taking them as much together as we can, which means that virtual particle interchange between them can be more energetic, so massive unknown particles may result from that. So it's not really about what you combine with what  (which also plays a role), but the most important part is how strong you collide them. So that weird things happened when particles become super close, different or same types of particles.

Comment: I would like to point out that the standard model of particle physics developed slowly by fitting the data and observations, so in a real sense it is l the mathematical data base of  experimental observations  up to now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when particles collide? What particles can collide and what not? These questions are answered by knowing the Lagrangian of a theory, which is a function that tells you the dynamics of your objects. From the Lagrangian one can obtain the Feynman Rules, with which one draws the Feynman diagrams. Our current best theory is the [Standard Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_the_Standard_Model), and from its Lagrangian one can derive the interactions. As far as we know, an up quark and an electron cannot interact directly with each other, meaning that there isn't a vertex where an up quark and an electron interact with each other. They can interact via the exchange of a Photon or Weak Boson:
[image]
If this is what you mean by "collide" (which, despite many experiments being called "colliders", isn't a term that most theoretical particle physicists use), then this is your answer.
Up quark and down quark, that's a different story. In the SM Lagrangian, one can see that there is a quark-boson-quark vertex, meaning that two quarks can annihilate and produce a boson:
[image]
This boson will quickly decay into other particles. Which ones? The ones allowed by the Lagrangian! A lepton-antilepton pair, or an up-down quark pair, for example.

Ultimately, *electric charge* (which seems to be what you're interested in) is a number that must be conserved at each vertex, but that doesn't otherwise tell you what vertices are allowed and what aren't: you must study and understand the Lagrangian of your theory.

Comment: quark-quark ,can only to interact strong,weak and electromagnetic force .Or quark-lepton ,an only to interact weak and electromagnetic force.That is two particles can interact only with common forces.And me need to know Lagrangian and Feynman Rules, Then I will know how to draw a diagram.And they should also keep quantum numbers in the data set.You probably meant it in the report after "collision".I already knew everything else about the weak forces of quarks.But thanks anyway.Did I understand everything correctly?

Comment: @user338062 I don't think I understand your comment. Could you try to be more clear?

Comment: I edited comment now.And is comment what I understood.At first glance, the porridge seems to be clear to me. Did I get it right in past comment?

Comment: @user338062 there is a small caveat: quark-quark can interact via strong, weak, and em meaning that there are a quark-quark-gluon, quark-quark-wboson, and quark-quark-photon vertices. Instead, quark-lepton can interact via weak and em meaning that weak bosons and photons couple both to quarks and to leptons, but *not in the same vertex*: there isn't a quark-lepton-boson vertex in the SM. Everything else is correct.

Comment: Of course they would call it a collider, such machines have already been used in the form of ep colliders (eg HERA was such a collider that used electrons to probe nucleon internal structure).